# Active link only works for first nav link, rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an is_active? helper to define the active link in my nav bar. It works fine. But I have a clients page that has many clients in it (in a sidebar list), and when I click through each client, the page reloads and gets the url for the client id (/clientes/1, /clientes/2 ...). My is_active? only works for the first client (id=1). When I click the other clients the active class disappears.

my header view looks like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="container" id="container-header">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <%= link_to "Zetta Comunicação", root_path, class: "navbar-brand logo img-responsive" %>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="<%= is_active?(servicos_path) %>">
          <%= link_to "A Empresa", servicos_path %>
        </li>
        <li class="<%= is_active? (cliente_unique_path(1)) %>">
          <%= link_to "Clientes", cliente_unique_path(1) %>
        </li>
        <li class="<%= is_active?(new_contato_path) %>">
          <%= link_to "Contato", new_contato_path %>
        </li> 
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

the helper looks like this

```
def is_active?(link_path)
  if current_page?(link_path)
    "active"
  else
    ""
  end
end
```

I know that I am calling the first id (id=1) in my header view. But I don't know how to make this call the other ids..

If I take the (1) of the cliente_unique_path it works perfect for the clients page, but I get the following error in my other pages:

> No route matches {:action=>"cliente_unique", :controller=>"clientes"}
>   missing required keys: [:id]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would use jQuery in these situations. Like,
function activate(i){
("ul.nav li").removeClass("active");
("ul.nav li#" + i).addClass("active");
}

put that code in application.js. 
give ids to all your li items.
and in every page call that function in a script tag passing the id of the li that you want to activate.
(typing from phone, so forgive the readability)

Comment: It's not working for me..do you now any other solution?@beck03076